# How to show that $Y_1, Y_2$ are independent

Tags: probability-theory

Let $N,X_1,\ldots$ be independent random variables with $N\sim \mathrm{Poisson}(\lambda)$ and $X_k \sim \mathrm{Bernoulli}(1/2)$ for all $k\geq 1.$

Define $Y_1 = \sum_{k=1}^N X_k$ and $Y_2 = N-Y_1$.

If $N=0$ then $Y_1 = 0$.
How would I show that $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are independent?

I first found the distribution of $Y_1$, which is $\mathrm{Poisson}(\frac{\lambda}{2})$.

However, I'm not sure how to go from here.

Note that $Y_1|N \sim\mathrm{Binomial}(N,1/2)$, so
 $$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(Y_1 = y) &= \sum_{n = y}^\infty \mathbb{P}(Y_1 = y|N=n) \mathbb{P}(N=n)\\ &= \sum_{n=y}^\infty \binom{n}{y}(\frac{1}{2})^{n} \times \frac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^n}{n!} \\
&= \sum_{n=y}^\infty \frac{1}{(n-y)!y!}(\frac{\lambda}{2})^n \times e^{-\lambda}
\\ &= \frac{e^{-\lambda/2}}{y!}\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{e^{-\lambda/2}(\frac{\lambda}{2})^{y+i}}{i!} \\
&= \frac{(\frac{\lambda}{2})^y e^{-\lambda/2}}{y!} \times 1
\end{align}
$$
since the sum is just the density of a $\mathrm{Poisson}(\frac{\lambda}{2})$ distribution.

Comment: Could you show how you derive the distribution for $Y_1$? Also, are you sure $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are supposed to be independent? It really doesn't look like they are.

Comment: Yeah sure,I'll update it in the OP and yeah, that's what the question asked for so I'm not very sure

Comment: Added in. $$$$$$

Comment: Thanks -- I tried the same derivation and made a silly mistake along the way. Anyway, I think you can show that $\Pr(Y_1 = 0, Y_2 = 0)\neq \Pr(Y_1 = 0)\Pr(Y_2 = 0)$, which would imply that $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are not independent, hence my question from the last comment.

Comment: How do you find the Pr on the LHS? Also I made a big mistake in the question and edited in. The definition of $Y_2$ is $Y_2 = N -Y_1$.

Comment: ...well, the new definition of $Y_2$ changes everything, so my last comment is moot.

Comment: Sorry about that, although I'm still unsure how to approach it

Comment: I would try to calculate $\Pr(Y_1=k,Y_2=j)$ and show this is equal to $\Pr(Y_1=k)\Pr(Y_2 =j)$. I don't have time to work through this now, but hopefully you can make it work and post an answer. Calculating $\Pr(Y_2 =j)$ shouldn't be too hard, since I believe $Y_2$ is also Poisson($\lambda / 2$).

Comment: I'll try that , thanks$ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proceeding similarly by conditioning on $N$, you will find that $Y_2$ is also $\text{Poisson}(\lambda/2)$.

Finally, $P(Y_1=j,Y_2=k)=P(Y_1=j,N-Y_1=k)$

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad=P(Y_1=j,N=k+j)$

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad=P(Y_1=j\mid N=k+j)P(N=k+j)$

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad=\displaystyle\binom{k+j}{j}\left(\frac{\lambda}{2}\right)^{k+j}\frac{e^{-\lambda}}{(k+j)!}$

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad=\displaystyle\frac{e^{-\lambda}(\frac{\lambda}{2})^{k+j}}{k!j!}\mathbf1_{{j,k}\{0,1,2,\cdots\}}$

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad=\displaystyle P(Y_1=j)P(Y_2=k)$.

Comment: I'm not familiar with your notation in the indicator function. Or is that a typo?

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist By $\mathbf1_{{j,k}\{0,1,2,\cdots\}}$ I mean $j$ and $k$ both run from $0,1,2,...$ in the indicator variable.

Comment: I see. Normally I'd see that written as $\mathbf{1}_{j,k\in\{0,1,2,\ldots\}}$, but I suppose that works.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist Yes yours is definitely better.

Comment: Thanks, is it kind of counter-intuitive becauase the definition of $Y_2$ is that it changes *depending* on what $Y_1$ is?

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with the Poisson process, there's a more intuitive approach.  It's clear that each $Y_{i}$ is $Poisson(\lambda/2)$: Just imagine their sum as being generated by a Poisson process running for time 1 with force $\lambda$, which clearly gives the same joint $Y_{i}$ distribution as in the problem.  Clearly each $Y_{i}$ is the counts from a Poisson process running for time 1 with force $\lambda/2$.  Now consider $Z_{i}, i=1,2$ which are the results of Poisson processes running for time $1/2$ (on the intervals $[0,1/2)$ and $[1/2,1]$).  They each also are $Poisson(\lambda/2)$ and are clearly independent.  But the joint distribution of $N$ and $Z_{1}$ is the same as the joint distribution of $N$ and $Y_{1}$, since squishing the interval by a factor of 2 and doubling the force of the process changes nothing.  (Yes, you should work out the math behind this last sentence, but the point of this answer is to show why the result is intuitive.) Thus, since $Z_{1}$ and $N-Z_{1}$ are independent (independence of non-overlapping time intervals being a basic property of the Poisson process), so are $Y_{1}$ and $N-Y_{1}$.