# If $X$ is a random variable and I have another r.v. $Y = f(X)$, is $Y$ always dependent on $X$?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

If $X$ is a random variable and I have another r.v. $Y = f(X)$, is $Y$ always dependent on $X$?

I don't think so, becausein this Q: [How to show that $Y_1, Y_2$ are independent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2736395/how-to-show-that-y-1-y-2-are-independent)

$Y_2 = N - Y_1$ (which looks like the value of $Y_2$ must change *depending* on $Y_1$, but it's provable that $Y_1,Y_2$ are independent.)

If we have a random variable $X$, then is something like $Y = 5X$ *always* not independent?

Answer (score 3):

Well, if X is constant, then X is independent of Y for all Y, including Y=f(X), which will simply be some other constant.

If f and X are such that there is a number z such that f(X)=z with probability one, then Y=z with probability one and is thus independent of X.

Otherwise there is a w such that $P(Y>w)>0$ and $P(Y<w)>0$.  But then there are disjoint sets A, B with $X\in A$ when $Y<w$ and $X\in B$ when $Y>w$.  Thus X and Y are not independent.

To sum up, X and Y are independent in this case if and only if Y is equal to a constant with probability one (or "almost surely" as they say in probability theory).

By the way, in your example with $Y_{2}=N-Y_{1}$, assuming N to be a constant, the assertion is false unless $Y_{1}$ is almost surely constant.

Comment: $Y_1$ was defined to be sum of $N$ bernoulli r.v.s where $N\sim Bernoulli(1/2)$. Would $Y_1$ be "almost surely constant" here?

Comment: How come $Y$ will be independent of $X$ if $X$ is constant?  
What if $Y= 5X$ and $X = 1$ (with prob. $1$)? Then $Y = 5$ with prob. 1 and is determined by $X$

Comment: First, no $Y_{1}$ will not be almost surely constant.  "Almost surely" constant means equal to a single number with probability one.  In your example $Y_{1}$ is Bernoulli(1/4), since it has a 50% chance of being zero and a 50% chance of having a 50% chance of being zero or of being one.  If $X_{1}$, $X_{2}$,... are an infinite sequence of independent Bernoulli(1/2) variables, and Y is 0 if infinitely many of the $X_{i}$ are 0, and is 1 if only finitely many of the $X_{i}$ are zero, then Y is almost surely constant (because it equals zero with probability one).

Comment: All random variables are independent of a constant random variable X, because P(Y<a,X<b) = P(Y<a)P(X<b) for all numbers a and b and random variables Y.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is NO though. I'm not sure to which level your question is meant to ask, I'll give you a counter example. But I guess in most "normal cases", they should be dependent.

Here is the definition of two random variables being independent: $X$ and $Y$ are independent, if and only if events $A$ and $B$ are independent, that is $\mathbb P(A \cap B) = \mathbb P(A) \cdot \mathbb P(B)$, whenever $A \in \sigma(X)$ and $B \in \sigma(Y)$, where $\sigma(X)=\{X^{−1}(A)|A \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)\}$

Now let $X$ be a r.v. and let $f$ be a real valued function s.t. both $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are Borel measurable. Let $Y = f \circ X$ s.t. $\mathbb P(Y \le y) = 0 \text{ or } 1$. Then $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

$$\sigma(X)=\{X^{-1}(A)|A \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)\}=\{X^{-1}\circ f^{-1}\circ f(A)|A \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)\}$$

$$\sigma(Y)=\{(f\circ X)^{-1}(A)|A \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)\}=\{X^{-1} \circ f^{-1}(A)|A \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)\}$$

We have $\sigma(X)=\sigma(Y)$, and this is because: $f$ Borel-measurable, we get $\sigma(Y)\subset \sigma(X)$; $f^{-1}$ Borel-measurable, we get $\sigma(X) \subset \sigma(Y)$.

Now take a look at $\mathbb P (\{\omega: X(\omega) \le x \} \cap \{\omega: Y(\omega) \le y)\})$, no matter what value of $x, y$ we take, it will be the same as $\mathbb P(\{\omega: X(\omega) \le x\}) \cdot\mathbb P (\{\omega: Y(\omega) \le y\})$.

This is because:

If we take $y$ s.t. $\mathbb P(Y \le y)=0$, then $\{X \le x\} \cap \{Y \le y\} \subset \{Y \le y\}$, and thus $$0 \le \mathbb P (\{\omega: X(\omega) \le x \} \cap \{\omega: Y(\omega) \le y)\}) \le \mathbb P (X \le x) = 0$$

If we take $y$ s.t. $\mathbb P (Y \le y) = 1$, $\mathbb P( Y > y) = 0$, then $\{X \le x\} \cap \{Y \le y\} = \{ X \le x \} \setminus \{Y > y\}$, thus $$P(X \le x)=\mathbb P(X \le x) - \mathbb P(Y > y) \le \mathbb P (\{\omega: X(\omega) \le x \} \cap \{\omega: Y(\omega) \le y)\})$$ $$= \mathbb P(\{ X \le x \} \setminus \{Y > y\}) \le \mathbb P (X \le x)$$

Thus we have:

$$\mathbb P(X \le x, Y \le y) = \mathbb (X \le x) \cdot \mathbb (Y \le y)$$

So $X$ and $Y$ are independent in this example.

Answer (score 1):

By the way, in a different question ([How to show that $Y_1, Y_2$ are independent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2736395/how-to-show-that-y-1-y-2-are-independent/2738246#2738246)) you gave an example where N is a *random variable* and $Y_{1}$ and $Y_{2}$ are independent.  In this question you didn't say what $N$ was, so it was taken as a constant, since $N$ is often used for a constant.  So if you are wondering why answers to this question seem inconsistent with answers to that question, it's because the questions aren't as similar as you thought.